# How to Infinity Scroll using Intersection Observer API?

Tags: javascript

I wrote that API to implement infinite scrolling, but it doesn't quite recognize that I've reached the bottom of the page. Which option should I fix

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.